# Why do i receive 'Duplicate column name' error when innerjoin-ing 2 tables with similar column name?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE student_activestudent AS 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM
      student
   INNER JOIN
      activestudent ON activestudent.studentnumber=student.studentnumber
);
```

I am expecting a table with 2 columns of studentnumber but I received Duplicate error instead --> Duplicate column name 'studentnumber'

Comment: What DBMS is this for? Oracle?

Comment: don't use * instead specify column names as select student.studentnumber, student.column2 ....

Comment: ->its sql workbench, -> but if I have too many column names to specify, is there any other way for me to specify the column names?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the select are useless.

Answer (score 0):

A database table must have unique column names.
When you do `select *` you will get all columns from all tables and `studentnumber` exists on both `student` table and `activestudent` table. So to solve you problem specify the columns you want instead of `*`

```
 CREATE TABLE student_activestudent AS 
 (
   SELECT
     student.studentnumber,
     ..Other columns..
   FROM
      student
   INNER JOIN
      activestudent ON activestudent.studentnumber=student.studentnumber

 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I read from my lecture notes that if I have a query like this: 
mysql> SELECT * FROM
-> Names INNER JOIN Modules
-> ON Names.id = Modules.id;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 I will still get a table with 2 column named 'id' with similar data, that's why I don't understand why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: If you SELECT from 2 tables, you will still get a result set, even if the tables have duplicate column names; that is true.  however, when CREATING a table, all column names MUST be unique.  That is why it isn't working, despite your lecture notes.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, `studentnumber` is duplicated.  In general, I strongly recommend that a view list all the columns explicitly.  This protects the view if underlying columns change.

That said, if `studentnumber` is the *only* column, then you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE student_activestudent AS 
   SELECT * 
   FROM student s JOIN
        activestudent ast 
        USING (studentnumber);
```

With `using`, the `*` does not repeat the join keys.

Answer (score 0):

You  cannot select two tables that have same column's name.

The best way is not to select *

Select by column and if the column is same you can put [as]

Example

SELECT student.studentnumber as stuNumber, activestudent.studentnumber as actstuNumber